# An error occurred when attempting to create a React app (ERROR: Cannot find module './lib/_stream_transform.js')

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I am unable to create a react app even while running the proper commands.  Before attempting to create the React app, I run

```
node -v
npm -v
```

before running the following command:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Below, you can see a snippet of my terminal output of these commands, along with the error I get when running the create-react-app command.  If anyone has any ideas to solve this issue, I would greatly appreciate it!

```
PS C:\Users\codyd\Desktop\Second Monitor Icons\Coding Projects\JUST WORK PLEASE> node -v
v18.17.1
PS C:\Users\codyd\Desktop\Second Monitor Icons\Coding Projects\JUST WORK PLEASE> npm -v
9.8.1
PS C:\Users\codyd\Desktop\Second Monitor Icons\Coding Projects\JUST WORK PLEASE> npx create-react-app my-app
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './lib/_stream_transform.js'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\codyd\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\transform.js
- C:\Users\codyd\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\through2\through2.js
- C:\Users\codyd\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\hyperquest\index.js
- C:\Users\codyd\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js
- C:\Users\codyd\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\index.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:121:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\codyd\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\transform.js:1:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\codyd\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\c67e74de0542c87c\\node_modules\\through2\\node_modules\\readable-stream\\transform.js',
    'C:\\Users\\codyd\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\c67e74de0542c87c\\node_modules\\through2\\through2.js',
    'C:\\Users\\codyd\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\c67e74de0542c87c\\node_modules\\hyperquest\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\codyd\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\c67e74de0542c87c\\node_modules\\create-react-app\\createReactApp.js',
    'C:\\Users\\codyd\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\c67e74de0542c87c\\node_modules\\create-react-app\\index.js'
  ]
}

Node.js v18.17.1
PS C:\Users\codyd\Desktop\Second Monitor Icons\Coding Projects\JUST WORK PLEASE>
```

I have tried to clean the NPM cache (even with --force), but that didn't change anything.  I have tried reinstalling Node.js, but no change occurred.